# Interpolate 3D surface input into 4th dimension

Tags: numpy, scipy

My source data consists of a set of (x,y,z,e) samples. It can be visualized like this, where the dots are the (x,y,z) samples in 3D space and the color reflects the e value. The (x,y,z) samples compose a surface.

[image]

I want a kind of interpolation method, that I can feed with random (x,y,z) coordinates that are close to the surface and that can output an interpolated e value.

I tried the scipy [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html). It works fine, but only for input (x,y,z) points that lie inside the convex hull of the surface. When the input is only slightly outside, the interpolator returns 'nan'.

I'm a bit out of ideas how to solve this.

I can only think of iterating the each line in the grid to find the points closest to the random (x,y,z) input and do linear interpolations from these points. But if I could somehow reconstruct the surface, that would be more accurate.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "reconstruct the surface". What surface exactly? By taking the 3 closest points `p_i` to your input `x` and calculating `e` based on the relative distance from `x` to the `p_i` (i.e. weighted sum) you basically get a projection to the surface, or am I wrong here? What would be wrong with that approach?

Comment: I mean the surface you see in the picture. You say take 3 closest points (why 3?), but if my input `x` is relatively closer to one of the sides of the rectangular-like area's (in the picture), the `p_i` points will all be picked from the same side of `x`. For interpolation, the reference points should be on opposite sides of the input point, I'd assume? I'm going to try finding the 2 closest points on the vertical ribs and the 2 closest on the horizontal ribs, on opposite sides of `x` (tricky, because the ribs aren't evenly spaced and there's curvature), and interpolate those 4...

Comment: So my mind may be twisted with choosing 3 points, but the original idea was that 3 points are required to define a triangle (convex hull of `p_i`) which you could project `x` to. Every point in that convex hull has a defined value for `e`, it's only necessary to find the closest of these points (i.e. project `x` to it). My hope was that all this could be simply achieved by a weighted sum of `e` values from the `p_i` that span the triangle. Outside of the convex hull of your whole dataset (i.e. the original problem) this would lead to repeating the interpolated `e` values that are on the hull.